# Limiting nodes returned per group in a view

Tags: views

Using Drupal 7, I've created a view to render a list of most recent content types grouped by taxonomy. I can set a global limit for items returned but I'd instead like to limit it per group. So if I've got the terms "Apples", "Bananas" and "Carrots" I'd like to get the top three Apples, top three Bananas and top three Carrots. Currently I'm getting results such as top two Apples and one banana or top three apples.

**UPDATE**

I actually found a way to do it without creating multiple views. There's a module called [Views Grouping Row Limit](http://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping) that does exactly that I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were trying to accomplish this, I'd create multiple views attachments to do this. Then you can limit the number for each easily in the pager settings.

Comment: Thanks Beth, that's what I was thinking, too, just hoping to avoid having to create and edit a bunch of views every time.

Comment: If you use "clone view" after making the first one, and you don't override defaults for anything that you want most or all of the views to inherit, it should be pretty maintainable.